Importing a .tak file into Blender
I used an Optitrack system to capture motion and the files saved to my SSD as .tak files, not .bvh. Is there any way I can a) convert these files into .bvh or b) import them directly into Blender?

Are you sure there’s no alternate export option?

I found that OptiTrack has an official Blender addon for live streaming data in, but I don’t see any way to import pre-recorded tak files.

Per OptiTrack documentation, .tak ”Take” files are not exports, rather OptiTrack’s native save format, and it does export to both FBX and BVH as well as other formats.
